# Phaser3 JS : I got an error with rexPlugin

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_currentQuest') main.js:67

I tri to change my code but all time i already have this error...

If someone help me that will be great.
Idk what can i change in my code because i see tutorial and i write like the tuto / answer

```js
var questString = [
  ["type", "key", "next", "end"],
  ["q", "Va parler à Connor", "", ""],
  ["","", "Fini", "", ""],
  ["q", "Fini", "", "1"],
].map(x => x.join(",")).join("\n");

class SceneStart extends Phaser.Scene {

  constructor() {
    super({key: 'sceneStart'})
  }

  //Chargement des images
  preload() {
    this.load.plugin('rexquestplugin', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rexrainbow/phaser3-rex-notes/master/dist/rexquestplugin.min.js', true);

    this.load.image("player", "javascript/assets/player.png");
    this.load.image("run1", "javascript/assets/run1.png");
    this.load.image("run2", "javascript/assets/run2.png");
    this.load.image("playerLeftRun1", "javascript/assets/playerLeftRun1.png");
    this.load.image("playerLeftRun2", "javascript/assets/playerLeftRun2.png");
    this.load.image("door", "javascript/assets/doors.png");
    this.load.image("wall", "javascript/assets/walls.png");
    /** 
    this.load.image("fireStart1", "javascript/assets/fireStart1.png");
    this.load.image("fireStart2", "javascript/assets/fireStart2.png");
    this.load.image("fireStart3", "javascript/assets/fireStart3.png");
    */
  }

  handleMeeting(player, Connor){
    if(player._currentQuest){
      console.info(player._currentQuest.currentQuest)
      let options = player._currentQuest.currentQuest.options;
      if (options[0].next == "Va parler à Connor") {
        console.log("test mon reuf");
        player._currentQuest.manager.getNextQuestion(options[0].next);
      } else if (options[0].next == "Fini"){
        this.doorStart.visible = true;
        player._currentQuest.manager.getNextQuestion(options[0].next);
        this.physics.add.collider(player, doorStart, collision, undefined, this);
      }
    }
  }

  checkDoorStatus(player, door){
    return door.visible == false;
}

  create() {
    cursor = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys(); //touches des fleches
    platforms = this.physics.add.staticGroup();

    this.print = this.add.text(380, 180, '', { fontSize: '12px', align: 'right' }).setOrigin(1);

    this.plugins.get('rexquestplugin').add({
      questions: questString,
      quest: true
    }).on('quest', function (currentQuest, manager, quest) {
      // La quête est fini
      if (currentQuest.end === 1) {
          manager.setData('endAt', currentQuest.key);
          manager.emit('complete', manager, quest);
      } else {
          // Prochaine étape de la quête
          if(player._currentQuest ){ 
              this.print.text = this.print.text + 'done\n';
          }
          this.print.text += `${currentQuest.key}...`;
          this.player._currentQuest = { currentQuest, manager}
      }
  }, this).on('complete', function (manager, quest) {
      delete this.player._currentQuest;
      this.print.text = this.print.text + 'done\n';
      this.print.text += `\nDoor is unlocked!`;
  }, this).getNextQuestion();

    //Les animations 
    this.anims.create({
      key : "playerWalkUp",
      frames : [
        {key : "run1"},
        {key : "run2"}],
      frameRate : 7,
      repeat : 0
    })

    this.anims.create({
      key : "playerWalkLeft",
      frames : [
        {key : "playerLeftRun1"},
        {key : "playerLeftRun2"}],
      frameRate : 7,
      repeat : 0
    })

    /**
     * this.anims.create({
     * key : "fireMouvement",
     * frames : [
     * {key : "fireStart1"},
     * {key : "fireStart2"},
     * {key : "fireStart3"}],
     * framerate : 7,
     * repeat : -1
     * })
     */

    player = this.physics.add.sprite((w / 2), h, "player"); //joueur
    player.setScale(1, 1);
    player.body.setSize(30, 35);
    player.setCollideWorldBounds(true); //collision avec la bordure

    Connor = this.physics.add.sprite(160, 300, "player")
    Connor.setScale(1, 1);
    Connor.body.setSize(30, 35);

    wall1 = this.add.sprite(200, 146, "wall");
    wall1.setScale(0.3);

    wall2 = this.add.sprite(200, 445, "wall");
    wall2.setFlip(false, true);
    wall2.setScale(0.3);

    wall3 = this.add.sprite((w - 200), 146, "wall");
    wall3.setScale(0.3);

    wall4 = this.add.sprite((w - 200), 445, "wall");
    wall4.setFlip(false, true);
    wall4.setScale(0.3);

    doorStart = this.physics.add.staticSprite((w / 2), 28, "door"); //Porte principale
    doorStart.setScale(0.3);
    doorStart.body.setSize(300, 55);
    doorStart.body.setOffset(-56, 472);
    doorStart.rotation += -20.42;
    doorStart.visible = false;

    platforms.add(wall1);
    platforms.add(wall2);
    platforms.add(wall3);
    platforms.add(wall4);

    this.physics.add.collider(platforms, player); //collision
    this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.Connor, this.handleMeeting, undefined, this);
    
    
    //Fonction de collision qui éxecute le code dedans quand la fonctions est appelé
    function collision() {
      this.scene.start("labyrintheStart");
    }
  }

  update() {

    // Tous les mouvement sont controler par ce code
  
    if (cursor.left.isDown){
      player.setVelocityX(-200); //vitesse de deplacements
      player.anims.play("playerWalkLeft", true); //animations du personnage
      player.setFlip(false, false); //oriantation de l'image
    } else if (cursor.right.isDown){
      player.setVelocityX(200);
      player.anims.play("playerWalkLeft", true);
      player.setFlip(true, false);
    } else if (cursor.up.isDown){
      player.setVelocityY(-200);
      player.anims.play("playerWalkUp", true);
      player.setFlip(false, false);
    } else if (cursor.down.isDown){
      player.setVelocityY(200);
      player.anims.play("playerWalkUp", true);
      player.setFlip(false, true);
    } else {
      player.setVelocity(0);
      player.setTexture("player");
    }

    if ((cursor.left.isDown && cursor.up.isDown) || (cursor.left.isDown && cursor.right.isDown) || (cursor.left.isDown && cursor.down.isDown) || (cursor.right.isDown && cursor.up.isDown) || (cursor.right.isDown && cursor.down.isDown)){
      player.setVelocity(0);
      player.setTexture("player");
    }

  //--------
  }
}

class LabyrintheStart extends Phaser.Scene {

  constructor() {
   super({key: 'labyrintheStart'});
  }
  preload() {
    this.load.plugin('rexquestplugin', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rexrainbow/phaser3-rex-notes/master/dist/rexquestplugin.min.js', true);

    this.load.image("player", "javascript/assets/player.png");
    this.load.image("run1", "javascript/assets/run1.png");
    this.load.image("run2", "javascript/assets/run2.png");
    this.load.image("playerLeftRun1", "javascript/assets/playerLeftRun1.png");
    this.load.image("playerLeftRun2", "javascript/assets/playerLeftRun2.png");
    this.load.image("wall", "javascript/assets/walls.png"); 
    this.load.image("door", "javascript/assets/doors.png");
  }
   
  create() {
    cursor = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
    platforms = this.physics.add.staticGroup();


    this.anims.create({
      key : "playerWalkUp",
      frames : [
        {key : "run1"},
        {key : "run2"}],
      frameRate : 7,
      repeat : 0
    })
    
    this.anims.create({
      key : "playerWalkLeft",
      frames : [
        {key : "playerLeftRun1"},
        {key : "playerLeftRun2"}],
      frameRate : 7,
      repeat : 0
    })

    player = this.physics.add.sprite(34, h, "player");
    player.setScale(1, 1);
    player.body.setSize(30, 35);
        
    wall1 = this.add.sprite(9, h - 126, "wall");
    wall1.setScale(0.05);

    doorDroite = this.physics.add.staticSprite(w - 35, (h / 2) - 20, "door"); 
    doorDroite.setSize(18, 80);
    doorDroite.setScale(0.08);

    platforms.add(wall1);
    this.physics.add.collider(platforms, player);
    player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);

    function collisionDroite() {
      this.scene.start("labyrintheDeux");
    }
    
    this.physics.add.collider(player, doorDroite, collisionDroite, undefined, this);
  }

  update() {

      if (cursor.left.isDown){
        player.setVelocityX(-200);
        player.anims.play("playerWalkLeft", true);
        player.setFlip(false, false);
      } else if (cursor.right.isDown){
        player.setVelocityX(200);
        player.anims.play("playerWalkLeft", true);
        player.setFlip(true, false);
      } else if (cursor.up.isDown){
        player.setVelocityY(-200);
        player.anims.play("playerWalkUp", true);
        player.setFlip(false, false);
      } else if (cursor.down.isDown){
        player.setVelocityY(200);
        player.anims.play("playerWalkUp", true);
        player.setFlip(false, true);
      } else {
        player.setVelocity(0);
        player.setTexture("player");
      }
  
      if ((cursor.left.isDown && cursor.up.isDown) || (cursor.left.isDown && cursor.right.isDown) || (cursor.left.isDown && cursor.down.isDown) || (cursor.right.isDown && cursor.up.isDown) || (cursor.right.isDown && cursor.down.isDown)){
        player.setVelocity(0);
        player.setTexture("player");
      }
  }
}
/**
class LabyrintheDeux extends Phaser.Scene {

  constructor() {
    super({key: "labyrintheDeux"});
  }

  preload() {
    this.load.plugin('rexquestplugin', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rexrainbow/phaser3-rex-notes/master/dist/rexquestplugin.min.js', true);

    this.load.image("player", "javascript/assets/player.png");
    this.load.image("run1", "javascript/assets/run1.png");
    this.load.image("run2", "javascript/assets/run2.png");
    this.load.image("playerLeftRun1", "javascript/assets/playerLeftRun1.png");
    this.load.image("playerLeftRun2", "javascript/assets/playerLeftRun2.png");
    this.load.image("wall", "javascript/assets/wall.png"); 
    this.load.image("doorStart", "javascript/assets/door.png");
  }

  create() {
    cursor = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
    platforms = this.physics.add.staticGroup();

    this.anims.create({
      key : "playerWalkUp",
      frames : [
        {key : "run1"},
        {key : "run2"}],
      frameRate : 7,
      repeat : 0
    })

    this.anims.create({
      key : "playerWalkLeft",
      frames : [
        {key : "playerLeftRun1"},
        {key : "playerLeftRun2"}],
      frameRate : 7,
      repeat : 0
    })

    player = this.physics.add.sprite((w - w) + 70, h, "player");
    player.setScale(1, 1);
    player.body.setSize(30, 35);
    
    wall = this.add.sprite((w - w) + 6, h - 126, "wall");

    door = this.physics.add.staticSprite((w / 2) - 20, 30, "door");
    door.rotation += 20.42;
    door.setSize(50, 10);

    platforms.add(wall);
    this.physics.add.collider(platforms, player);
    player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
    
    function collision() {
      this.scene.start("");
    }
    
    this.physics.add.collider(player, door, collision, undefined, this);
  }

  update() {
  
      if (cursor.left.isDown){
        player.setVelocityX(-200);
        player.anims.play("playerWalkLeft", true);
        player.setFlip(false, false);
      } else if (cursor.right.isDown){
        player.setVelocityX(200);
        player.anims.play("playerWalkLeft", true);
        player.setFlip(true, false);
      } else if (cursor.up.isDown){
        player.setVelocityY(-200);
        player.anims.play("playerWalkUp", true);
        player.setFlip(false, false);
      } else if (cursor.down.isDown){
        player.setVelocityY(200);
        player.anims.play("playerWalkUp", true);
        player.setFlip(false, true);
      } else {
        player.setVelocity(0);
        player.setTexture("player");
      }
  
      if ((cursor.left.isDown && cursor.up.isDown) || (cursor.left.isDown && cursor.right.isDown) || (cursor.left.isDown && cursor.down.isDown) || (cursor.right.isDown && cursor.up.isDown) || (cursor.right.isDown && cursor.down.isDown)){
        player.setVelocity(0);
        player.setTexture("player");
      }
  }

}
*/

var config = {
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  width: 1346,
  height: 561,
  backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF", //#FFFFFF
  physics: {
    default : "arcade",
    arcade : {
      debug : true,
    }
  },
  scene: [SceneStart, LabyrintheStart /**, LabyrintheDeux*/]
};

let game = new Phaser.Game(config);

var h = window.innerHeight;
var w = window.innerWidth;

var platforms;
var cursor;
var player;

var doorGauche;
var doorDroite;
var doorUp;
var doorStart;

var wall1;
var wall2;
var wall3;
var wall4;


// A rajouter plus tard
/**
 * 
    function collisionUp() {
      this.scene.start("labyrintheTrois");
    }
 * 
 * this.physics.add.collider(player, doorGauche, collisionUp, undefined, this); 
 * 
 * doorUp = this.physics.add.staticSprite((w / 2) - 20, 8, "door");
 * doorUp.setScale(0.08);
 * doorUp.setSize(80, 18);
 * doorUp.setOffset(55, 491);
 * doorUp.rotation += -20.42;
*/
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
<script id="js" type="text/javascript" src="javascript/main.js"></script>
<script></script>
```

Comment: On line 67 you use variable `player` which is not defined or passed in current scope - it is _undefined_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several points to fix:

- the is mixture of global variables and property, *choose one an stick to it*.

  - simple solution replace all `this.player` with `player`
- define the player variable before starting the quest. *(since the quest tries to access the `player` variable)*

  - simple solution move the `player` definition ontop on the quest definition `this.plugins.get('rexquestplugin')`.
- The variable `Connor` is not defined

  - simple solution add `var Connor;` to your code

**Here you can see this changes implemented:**

```js
// FIX number 3
var Connor;

var questString = [
  ["type", "key", "next", "end"],
  ["q", "Va parler à Connor", "", ""],
  ["","", "Fini", "", ""],
  ["q", "Fini", "", "1"],
].map(x => x.join(",")).join("\n");

class SceneStart extends Phaser.Scene {

  constructor() {
    super({key: 'sceneStart'})
  }

  //Chargement des images
  preload() {
    this.load.plugin('rexquestplugin', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rexrainbow/phaser3-rex-notes/master/dist/rexquestplugin.min.js', true);

    this.load.image("player", "javascript/assets/player.png");
    this.load.image("run1", "javascript/assets/run1.png");
    this.load.image("run2", "javascript/assets/run2.png");
    this.load.image("playerLeftRun1", "javascript/assets/playerLeftRun1.png");
    this.load.image("playerLeftRun2", "javascript/assets/playerLeftRun2.png");
    this.load.image("door", "javascript/assets/doors.png");
    this.load.image("wall", "javascript/assets/walls.png");
    /** 
    this.load.image("fireStart1", "javascript/assets/fireStart1.png");
    this.load.image("fireStart2", "javascript/assets/fireStart2.png");
    this.load.image("fireStart3", "javascript/assets/fireStart3.png");
    */
  }

  handleMeeting(player, Connor){
    if(player._currentQuest){
      console.info(player._currentQuest.currentQuest)
      let options = player._currentQuest.currentQuest.options;
      if (options[0].next == "Va parler à Connor") {
        console.log("test mon reuf");
        player._currentQuest.manager.getNextQuestion(options[0].next);
      } else if (options[0].next == "Fini"){
        this.doorStart.visible = true;
        player._currentQuest.manager.getNextQuestion(options[0].next);
        this.physics.add.collider(player, doorStart, collision, undefined, this);
      }
    }
  }

  checkDoorStatus(player, door){
    return door.visible == false;
}

  create() {
    cursor = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys(); //touches des fleches
    platforms = this.physics.add.staticGroup();

    this.print = this.add.text(380, 180, '', { fontSize: '12px', align: 'right' }).setOrigin(1);
    
    // FIX number 1
    player = this.physics.add.sprite((w / 2), h, "player"); //joueur
    player.setScale(1, 1);
    player.body.setSize(30, 35);
    player.setCollideWorldBounds(true); //collision avec la bordure
    

    this.plugins.get('rexquestplugin').add({
      questions: questString,
      quest: true
    }).on('quest', function (currentQuest, manager, quest) {
      // La quête est fini
      if (currentQuest.end === 1) {
          manager.setData('endAt', currentQuest.key);
          manager.emit('complete', manager, quest);
      } else {
          // Prochaine étape de la quête
          if(player._currentQuest ){ 
              this.print.text = this.print.text + 'done\n';
          }
          this.print.text += `${currentQuest.key}...`;
          // Fix number 1
          player._currentQuest = { currentQuest, manager}
      }
  }, this).on('complete', function (manager, quest) {
      // Fix number 1
      delete player._currentQuest;
      this.print.text = this.print.text + 'done\n';
      this.print.text += `\nDoor is unlocked!`;
  }, this).getNextQuestion();

  


    Connor = this.physics.add.sprite(160, 300, "player")
    Connor.setScale(1, 1);
    Connor.body.setSize(30, 35);

    wall1 = this.add.sprite(200, 146, "wall");
    wall1.setScale(0.3);

    wall2 = this.add.sprite(200, 445, "wall");
    wall2.setFlip(false, true);
    wall2.setScale(0.3);

    wall3 = this.add.sprite((w - 200), 146, "wall");
    wall3.setScale(0.3);

    wall4 = this.add.sprite((w - 200), 445, "wall");
    wall4.setFlip(false, true);
    wall4.setScale(0.3);

    doorStart = this.physics.add.staticSprite((w / 2), 28, "door"); //Porte principale
    doorStart.setScale(0.3);
    doorStart.body.setSize(300, 55);
    doorStart.body.setOffset(-56, 472);
    doorStart.rotation += -20.42;
    doorStart.visible = false;

    platforms.add(wall1);
    platforms.add(wall2);
    platforms.add(wall3);
    platforms.add(wall4);

    this.physics.add.collider(platforms, player); //collision
    // Fix number 1
    this.physics.add.collider(player, Connor, this.handleMeeting, undefined, this);
    
    
    //Fonction de collision qui éxecute le code dedans quand la fonctions est appelé
    function collision() {
      this.scene.start("labyrintheStart");
    }
  }

  update() {

    // Tous les mouvement sont controler par ce code
  
    if (cursor.left.isDown){
      player.setVelocityX(-200); //vitesse de deplacements
      player.anims.play("playerWalkLeft", true); //animations du personnage
      player.setFlip(false, false); //oriantation de l'image
    } else if (cursor.right.isDown){
      player.setVelocityX(200);
      player.anims.play("playerWalkLeft", true);
      player.setFlip(true, false);
    } else if (cursor.up.isDown){
      player.setVelocityY(-200);
      player.anims.play("playerWalkUp", true);
      player.setFlip(false, false);
    } else if (cursor.down.isDown){
      player.setVelocityY(200);
      player.anims.play("playerWalkUp", true);
      player.setFlip(false, true);
    } else {
      player.setVelocity(0);
      player.setTexture("player");
    }

    if ((cursor.left.isDown && cursor.up.isDown) || (cursor.left.isDown && cursor.right.isDown) || (cursor.left.isDown && cursor.down.isDown) || (cursor.right.isDown && cursor.up.isDown) || (cursor.right.isDown && cursor.down.isDown)){
      player.setVelocity(0);
      player.setTexture("player");
    }

  //--------
  }
}

class LabyrintheStart extends Phaser.Scene {

  constructor() {
   super({key: 'labyrintheStart'});
  }
  preload() {
    this.load.plugin('rexquestplugin', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rexrainbow/phaser3-rex-notes/master/dist/rexquestplugin.min.js', true);

    this.load.image("player", "javascript/assets/player.png");
    this.load.image("run1", "javascript/assets/run1.png");
    this.load.image("run2", "javascript/assets/run2.png");
    this.load.image("playerLeftRun1", "javascript/assets/playerLeftRun1.png");
    this.load.image("playerLeftRun2", "javascript/assets/playerLeftRun2.png");
    this.load.image("wall", "javascript/assets/walls.png"); 
    this.load.image("door", "javascript/assets/doors.png");
  }
   
  create() {
    cursor = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
    platforms = this.physics.add.staticGroup();


    this.anims.create({
      key : "playerWalkUp",
      frames : [
        {key : "run1"},
        {key : "run2"}],
      frameRate : 7,
      repeat : 0
    })
    
    this.anims.create({
      key : "playerWalkLeft",
      frames : [
        {key : "playerLeftRun1"},
        {key : "playerLeftRun2"}],
      frameRate : 7,
      repeat : 0
    })

    player = this.physics.add.sprite(34, h, "player");
    player.setScale(1, 1);
    player.body.setSize(30, 35);
        
    wall1 = this.add.sprite(9, h - 126, "wall");
    wall1.setScale(0.05);

    doorDroite = this.physics.add.staticSprite(w - 35, (h / 2) - 20, "door"); 
    doorDroite.setSize(18, 80);
    doorDroite.setScale(0.08);

    platforms.add(wall1);
    this.physics.add.collider(platforms, player);
    player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);

    function collisionDroite() {
      this.scene.start("labyrintheDeux");
    }
    
    this.physics.add.collider(player, doorDroite, collisionDroite, undefined, this);
  }

  update() {

      if (cursor.left.isDown){
        player.setVelocityX(-200);
        player.anims.play("playerWalkLeft", true);
        player.setFlip(false, false);
      } else if (cursor.right.isDown){
        player.setVelocityX(200);
        player.anims.play("playerWalkLeft", true);
        player.setFlip(true, false);
      } else if (cursor.up.isDown){
        player.setVelocityY(-200);
        player.anims.play("playerWalkUp", true);
        player.setFlip(false, false);
      } else if (cursor.down.isDown){
        player.setVelocityY(200);
        player.anims.play("playerWalkUp", true);
        player.setFlip(false, true);
      } else {
        player.setVelocity(0);
        player.setTexture("player");
      }
  
      if ((cursor.left.isDown && cursor.up.isDown) || (cursor.left.isDown && cursor.right.isDown) || (cursor.left.isDown && cursor.down.isDown) || (cursor.right.isDown && cursor.up.isDown) || (cursor.right.isDown && cursor.down.isDown)){
        player.setVelocity(0);
        player.setTexture("player");
      }
  }
}

var config = {
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  width: 400,
  height: 200,
  backgroundColor: "#000000", //#FFFFFF
  physics: {
    default : "arcade",
    arcade : {
      debug : true,
    }
  },
  scene: [SceneStart, LabyrintheStart /**, LabyrintheDeux*/]
};

let game = new Phaser.Game(config);

var h = window.innerHeight;
var w = window.innerWidth;

var platforms;
var cursor;
var player;

var doorGauche;
var doorDroite;
var doorUp;
var doorStart;

var wall1;
var wall2;
var wall3;
var wall4;
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

**btw.:** you should always remove code you are not using, might cause error. I hope this helps.